# PHP Reading string as exponential number

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am reading a CSV file to import data. I am having a column with some auto-generated numbers(text & Numbers). The problem is in some of the rows my script reads the value as exponential number.
[image]

Example: 58597E68 is considered 5.86E+72

I need it to read as String as not number. The issue occurs only if I am having the character (E) in middle of the auto-generated number.

```
$feed = 'path-to-csv/import.csv';
    if (!file_exists($feed)) {
        //$feed = 'import.csv';
        exit('Cannot find the CSV file: ' . $feed);
    }
    $row=0;

    if (($handle = fopen($feed, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data_csv_rows = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ',')) !== FALSE) {

            $row++;
            if ($row == 1) {
                continue;
            } // skipping header row
            echo "Row " . ($row-1) . "<br>";print_r($data_csv_rows);echo "<br><br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us sample of the data and the way how the data are read from csv, ie the code.

Comment: I have added the code to the question.

Comment: Please show us the CSV data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your CSV but the original software (probably Excel) that produced the CSV.

CSV is a simple data format when you find something like `5.86E+72` it's like that in the CSV data and it's too late to fix it.

To avoid this make sure you [**export** the data correct into CSV](http://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP06_KnowledgeWithSidebarTroubleshoot?id=kA280000000TTCfCAO&popup=false&lang=en_US).

Some PHP code to find this kind of bad data in a field:

```
if (strpos($value, 'E+') !== FALSE) {
    preg_match('~E\+[0-9]+$~', $value, $preg_result);
        if (isset($preg_result[0])) {
            die('Probably wrong data found within "'.$value.'".');
        }
    }
}
```

---

In your case [it seems](https://3v4l.org/a1snU) that `58597E68` is converted to `float(5.8597E+72)`.

At least with [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/function.str-getcsv.php) I can not recreate the problem, see https://3v4l.org/RZ1eA.

By [definition](http://php.net/manual/language.types.float.php) it would be correct, since there are no " around this data, so PHP tries to determinate the type of this data and if it is potentally a numeric value... So be sure add " around strings. [PHP String to Numeric Conversion documentation](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

---

Update: **I can not reproduce your use-case!** `58597E68` becomes `"58597E68"` with `str_getcsv()` and with `fgetcsv()` It is not autoconverted to float! See https://3v4l.org/oXkBu for details! I suspect there is something wrong with the data you provide us or your validation.

Comment: You are right but I can see the string correctly when i open it in an editor(notepad) is there any way i could convert it to string if such case occurs

Comment: I see, (https://3v4l.org/a1snU) you still could use my code and return `(string)$value` in the case of a match ...

Comment: Hi

{ "FALSE","TRUE","False","False",,,,,,"Flat 117","58597E68","{44613829-0D2B-459E-B722-07B03C7501B3}" }

This is the row from the CSV file. There are already  " added to the string. Also When I open the CSV in notepad 58597E68 is displayed and when opened in MS-Excel 5.8597E+72 is displayed.